# Which is better transform or views::transform for conversion?

Tags: c++, std-ranges

Is there a difference between the two provided examples? Is one more preferrable over the other?

```cpp
std::vector<source> sources;
std::vector<dest> dests;
dests.reserve(sources.size());
std::ranges::transform(sources.begin(), sources.end(), std::back_inserter(dests), trFunction);
```

```cpp
std::vector<source> sources;
auto view = sources | std::ranges::views::transform(trFunction);
std::vector<dest> dests{ view.begin(), view.end() };
```

Comment: Unrelated: You probably have an unintended headshot here at `std::vector<dest> dests{ sources.size() };`. It will not provide a `vector` with `sources.size()` slots, the curly braces tell the compiler to use an the parameters as a list of items to go into the `vector`, so you get exactly one item in the `vector`, and it contains the value of `sources.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st way is incorrect. You should not both construct a non-zero-sized vector and use `back_insterter`. I.e., you can either:

```
//1a
std::vector<dest> dests;
dest.reserve( source.size() );
std::ranges::transform(sources.begin(), sources.end(), std::back_inserter(dests), trFunction);
```

or

```
//1b
std::vector<dest> dests( sources.size() ); //use (), not {}!
std::ranges::transform(sources.begin(), sources.end(), dests.begin(), trFunction);
```

Above, 1a is more flexible, because 1b requires `dest` to have a default constructor (and default-constructing all objects can be inefficient even if the default constructor is available).

Your 2nd version (using `views::transform`) is probably equivalent to 1a. Its only advantage is that it can be later extended with other views (e.g., if you also need to filter source elements).